# phpmailer success but no email sent

Tags: smtp, phpmailer

PHPMailer says successful but email is not being sent. Email trace doesn't show any errrors. From sending or receiving email. Is there something that I'm missing?

Below is my mailer.php file:

```
    require 'class.phpmailer.php';
require 'class.smtp.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;


$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'localhost';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'diane@example.com';                            // SMTP username: FROM EMAIL
$mail->Password = 'pw';                           // SMTP password: FROM PW


$mail->From = 'diane@example.com'; //FROM EMAIL
$mail->addAddress('terry@example.com');               // Add a recipient, Name is optional


$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Contact Form';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure why you're using this method to send email in PHP. Here's a better way to accomplish this:

```
$to = 'test@test.com';
$subject = 'Lorem Ipsum';
$from = 'me@me.com';
$message = 'Congrats! You won! Message body here.';
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: Obviously this person needs to be able to use SMTP authentication for sending their email, so your basic solution is certainly not going to help them.